# Access global variable from external class

Tags: python, oop

How to structure an application so global variables work ?

I'm looking for the simplest way to do something like :

**main.py**

```
from Class_A import Class_A

my_var = 3

c_a = Class_A()
print c_a.get_var()
# ==> NameError: global name 'my_var' is not defined
```

**Class_A.py**

```
class Class_A:
    def get_var():
        global my_var
        return my_var
```

**Answer :**

Nagasaki45's answer is good, here is how to implement it :

main.py

```
from Class_A import Class_A
import Global_Vars

c_a = Class_A()

print Global_Vars.my_var
print c_a.get_var()

Global_Vars.my_var += 12

print c_a.get_var()
```

Class_A.py

```
import Global_Vars
class Class_A:
    def get_var(self):
        return Global_Vars.my_var
```

Global_Vars.py

```
import random
my_var = random.randint(0,100)
```

This outputs :

```
17
17
29
```

Comment: Is there a particularly good reason `my_var` can't be an instance attribute or method parameter?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to be able to use it in lots of modules and not only read it, but also edit it.

Comment: That only makes it *more* important to try to make `my_var` an explicit input and output rather than a `global`; it will make your code much easier to develop, test and debug as you will reduce the dependency between the various modules.

Comment: would you please show me an example?

Comment: ...of method parameters? `def get_var(self, my_var):`.

Comment: Hmm, this would be a terrible spaghetti mess, I have a few variables I want to be globals. Plus to edit the variable in one function I'd need to return it and set it again in main script...

Comment: There will be some up-front work to refactor around this, but [structure is key](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#structure-is-key).

Comment: Structure is important indeed, that's why I prefer to have a variable which is accessible globally than having to pass it to every function, return it, and re-set it every time it's updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two modules depends on same variable I would move it outside to a 3rd module and import it from there to both of them. Doing so you will end up with much less problems of circular imports.

In any case, the `global` keyword is used for setting global variables. Don't use it if you only want to get a variable value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want some object to be shared by other objects, pass this objects to the others, ie:

shared.py :

```
import random

class Shared(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.var = random.randint(0,100)
```

lib.py :

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, shared):
        self.shared = shared

    def get_var(self):
        return self.shared.var
```

main.py :

```
from shared import Shared
import lib

shared = Shared()
obj = lib.MyClass(shared)

print "shared.var : ", shared.var
print "obj.get_var() : ", obj.get_var()
shared.var = 200
print "shared.var : ", shared.var
print "obj.get_var() : ", obj.get_var()
```

Note that you don't need any "global" variable here.

Answer (score 1):

Hum ... am I totally wrong, of the real answer does not have anything to do with *globals* ?

You have to know that Python variables are mostly *tags* that references values. And `integer` are immutable. So, after that call:

```
gv.my_var += 12
```

`gv.my_var` *references* a different value (`36`). This only change *this* reference. Other references to `24` are not affected.